# Does a potion of growth stack with the Enlarge spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, potions, stacking

If I drink a [*potion of growth*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-growth), and a wizard casts [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) on me, do they add together as separate effects to give me 2 size increases, or do they simply override each other and give me the better duration?

Asking for purposes of grappling gargantuan creatures as a huge player.

Comment: Note to voters: the *player* is huge... you might want to vote the way he wants. =)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## No. They don't.

The *potion of growth* states:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the "enlarge" effect of the *enlarge/reduce* spell for 1d4 hours (no concentration required).

If a Wizard casts *enlarge/reduce* on you, then you will now be experiencing the same magical effect twice, simultaneously It would be no different if two Wizards had cast the same spell on you at the same time.

Since the same game effects don't overlap, the *potion of growth* does not interact with the *enlarge/reduce* spell.

> **[DMG Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf)**.
>
> **Combining Game Effects (p. 252)** [...]  "Different game features can
>   affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features
>   have the same name, only the effects of one of them -- the
>   most potent one -- apply while the durations of the effects overlap. [...] Game features include **spells**, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and **magic items**."

Comment: While the DMG says "same name" that's not really correct.   Magic items often don't match the relevant spells yet they're really the same effect.  If the magic item has all the same parameters as the spell then figure it probably is the spell unless you have evidence otherwise.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Are you agreeing or disagreeing with this answer?

Comment: @LorenPechtel Do you have any evidence (published rules, Sage Advice material, commentary from the designers) that supports your assertion?

Comment: Regarding that DMG Errata: it specifies Fire Form in the example, and I can understand two Fire Form damages don't stack. However, does Fire Form and Flaming Sphere not stack as well as they're game features of burning? I think it's relevant, as Potion of Growth is obviously a different name than the spell Enlarge/Reduce, unless it's the game feature of Enlarge that counts. I'm of the idea that if you have to describe the effect relating it to a game mechanic then it counts, but I'd like to know if I'm off base with that and the question seemed too closely related to this to post on its own

Answer (score -4):

My understanding of why you can’t stack 2 enlarge spells on yourself is because the spell requires concentration. But if it’s from an outside source that specifies no concentration needed it seems like the potion is quite different from the spell. So I would say yes, yes you can be a big honking boy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).