# Does the Enlarge spell stack if it is cast multiple times?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, stacking

Does the [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) spell stack if it is cast multiple times?

In my campaign my character and party want to know if it is possible to cause our barbarian to become huge in size (two *enlarge* spells). If so that'd be amazing but I can definitely see how it'd be too busted with the extra size, range, damage, and all that.

Comment: Related/answer applies to this: [Does a potion of growth stack with enlarge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101536/does-a-potion-of-growth-stack-with-enlarge)

Comment: Related [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111244/is-there-a-way-to-increase-a-creatures-size-category-twice/)

Answer (score 57):

The rule on [Combining Magical Effects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) (PHB 205) states:

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine

So **no**, the effect of the *enlarge* spell can't be stacked on the same creature.